# Using Text::CSV to find text with round brackets - not working

Tags: perl

I have a csv file that I am searching for lines that contain a certain model. The program works perfectly when searching for '2GM' model but NOT for '2GM(F)'

This is the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Searches modeltest.txt for all instances of model
# Writes a file called <your model>.txt with all lines 
# in modeltest.txt where the model is found
# Edit $model for different uses
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
my $input_file = 'modeltest.txt';
my @lines = ();
# my $model = '2GM'; # Search for 2GM - WORKS PERFECTLY
my $model = '2GM(F)'; # Search for 2GM(F) - DOES NOT WORK!
# my $model = '2GM\(F\)'; # Does not work either!
print "Search pattern is $model\n";
my $output_file = $model . '.txt';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol=> "\012"})
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

print "Searching modeltest.txt for $model....\n";

open my $infh,  '<', $input_file or die "Can't open   '$input_file':$!" ;
open my $outfh, '>', $output_file or die "Can't open '$output_file':$!" ;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($infh))
{
    my @fields = $csv->fields();
            if (/^($model)$/ ~~ @fields) # search for pattern
            {
            $csv->print ($outfh, ["Y $fields[1]",$model]) or     $csv->error_diag;
            }
}
close $infh;
close $outfh;

$csv->eof or die "Processing of '$input_file' terminated prematurely\n";
print "All Done see output files...\n";
```

Here is the modeltest.txt file:

```
3,721575-42702,121575-42000,"PUMP ASSY, WATER",,26,COOLING SEA WATER PUMP,-,2GM(F),3GM(F),-,3HM,3HMF,,

1,721575-42702,121575-42000,"PUMP ASSY, WATER",,73,COOLING SEA WATER PUMP,-,2GM,3GM,-,3HM,-,,

45,103854-59191,,"BOLT ASSY, JOINT M12",W,38,FUEL PIPE,1GM,2GM(F),3GM(F),3GMD,3HM,3HMF,,
21,104200-11180,,"RETAINER, SPRING",,11,CYLINDER HEAD,1GM,2GM(F),3GM(F),3GMD,-,-,,
24,23414-080000,,"GASKET, 8X1.0",,77,FUEL PIPE,-,2GM,3GM,-,3HM,-,,
3,124223-42092,124223-42091,IMPELLER,,73,COOLING SEA WATER PUMP,-,2GM,3GM,-,3HM,-,,
```

Here is the output for 2GM.txt

```
"Y 721575-42702",2GM
"Y 23414-080000",2GM
"Y 124223-42092",2GM
```

There is no output for 2GM(F) - the program does not work! and I have no idea why?
Can anyone throw some light onto my problem?

YES this Worked Thank you again !!
Happy not to be using smartmatch...
Did the following:

Changed the search expression to

```
my $model = "2GM\(F\)";
```

Used the following code

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline($infh))
{
    my @fields = $csv->fields();
            foreach my $field (@fields)
            {
            if ($model eq $field) # search for pattern match in any field
                {
                $csv->print ($outfh, ["Y $fields[1]",$model]) or $csv->error_diag;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If one of the below answers ends up being your final solution, please give them a checkmark to close out the question.  If both are useful, consider giving them both up votes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is best to use `\Q` in the regex so that you don't have to mess with escaping characters when you define `$model`.
- The data is already in the array referred to by `$row` - there is no need to call `fields` to fetch it again.
- It is much clearer, and may be slightly faster, to use `any` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil)
- It's tidier to `use autodie` if all you want to do is die on an IO error
- Setting `auto_diag` to a value greater than one will cause it to die in the case of any errors instead of just warning

This is a version of your own program with these issues altered

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;
use List::Util 'any';

my $input_file  = 'modeltest.txt';
my $model       = '2GM(F)';
my $output_file = "$model.txt";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, eol => $/, auto_diag => 2 })
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag;

open my $infh,  '<', $input_file;
open my $outfh, '>', $output_file;

print qq{Searching "$input_file" for "$model"\n};

while (my $row = $csv->getline($infh)) {
  if (any { /\Q$model/ } @$row) {
    $csv->print($outfh, ["Y $row->[1]",$model]);
  }
}

close $outfh;
```

Comment: Worked great used if (any {/^(\Q$model\E)$/} @$row)

Comment: @user3569180: If that's what you want then you may as well write `if (any { $_ eq $model } @$row) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses have a special meaning in regular expressions, they create [`capture groups`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups).

If you want to match literal parentheses(or any other special character) in a regular expression you need to escape them with backslashes, so your search pattern needs to be `2GM\(F\)`.

You can also use `\Q` and `\E` to disable special characters in your pattern match and leave your search pattern the same:

```
if (/^(\Q$model\E)$/ ~~ @fields) # search for pattern
...
```

The smartmatch operator `~~` is deprecated I believe, it would be more straightforward to loop over `@fields`:

```
foreach my $field ( $csv->fields() ) {
   if (/^($model)/ =~ $field) # search for pattern
   ...
}
```

And really there is no reason to pattern match when you can compare directly:

```
foreach my $field ( @{$csv->fields()} ) {
   if ($model eq $field) # search for pattern
   ...
}
```

Comment: That does make a lot of sense - Thank you..I made the change you suggested but still no output when searching for 2GM(F) ???

Comment: YES worked - Thank you see edit to orig question above